# Increment a value based upon adjacent cell, count restarts on next similar number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm going to keep this simple, but basically, I have a list of numbers that differ (0,0,1,2,0,0) that need to have a number incremented based on how many identical codes are in the list and restart when the number is counted again, the trouble is that this list won't be ordered numerically, below is an example of what I am looking to do:

```
A1    B1
0      1
0      2
0      3
1      1
0      1
0      2
2      1
3      2
2      1
2      2
0      1
```

Essentially I need a function that can the count and restart when the same number is counted again, in the adjacent column.

My apologies if the question is relatively easy, but excel is not my strong suit. Thank you.

Comment: Why is B8 *2* when A8 is the only *3*?

Answer (score 1):

In `B1` enter : `1`

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A2<>A1,1,B1+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can logically assume that the *2* in B8 is a typo then this should work.

B1 will always be a *1* since there is nothing above A1. Below that you just need a COUNTIF of column A from the current row up to the highest row that does not contain the value in the corresponding row.

The first sequence (whether there is only 1 or several) always needs to start at the first row; in this case row 1. An IFERROR can handle this anomaly.

In B1 use this formula and fill down.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:INDEX(A:A, IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14, 7, ROW($1:1)/(A$1:A1<>A1), 1), 1)), A1)
```

[image]